# Couldn't get facebook Pages and groups details with facebook C# SDK

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api

I have integrated facebook DLL into my desktop application (C#.Net), in this one need to authenticate facebook account via OAuth and its working correctly. I got Access Token also and email too. But i want to access users pages and groups also, for this i have mentioned extendedPermissions like below:

FacebookExtendedPermissions = "email,user_groups,publish_stream,manage_pages"

I have used below block of code for getting users Page details:

```
 FacebookClient _fb = new FacebookClient();
 _fb.AccessToken = FacebookOAuthResult.AccessToken;
 dynamic results = _fb.Get("/me/accounts");
```

But i'm gatting empty value in data. What i'm doing wrong here can't get it.

I have tried in other way too like this:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=" + longLivedToken);
                    request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;

                    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
                    using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                    {
                       string html = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
```

But again no luck.
Any help or pointers will be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: why are you using deprecated permissions? where did you copy that code from?

Comment: either way, manage_pages is still correct and should give you access to the pages of a user with /me/accounts. if you don´t get them, debug the access token and make sure it includes the manage_pages permission.

Comment: @luschn i have tried and included manage_pages only permission under 'Scope' parameter while generating login url but still i'm not getting pages details.And this access token is valid for 2 months.What do i do next?Thanks for reply.

Comment: as i said, debug the token: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/

Comment: Done debugging and found only 'public_profile' under scope section but i have given 'manage_pages' only. As i know public_profile is by default. Page scope is not including in request due to this access token shows only default info. How to get over it? please advice.

Comment: well, there´s the problem then. fix your login process to include manage_pages, make sure you get asked for that permission.

Comment: hey thanks,i have got the solution.I need to activate those scopes under my developer account and submit for review so that i can include all those approved scopes and get details.

Comment: you only need to submit for review after you finished your app. review is only neccessary when you want to go public.

Comment: How can i get the album details of any particular Page and Groups? I can get Pages by Get("/me/accounts") and Groups by Get("/me/groups").But can't get albums of Pages. How can i achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: please start reading the docs, it´s all in there. check out the api reference to find out which permissions and which endpoints you need.